# Check page width then apply css in jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, resize

I am trying to get jQuery to check the window width on resize. If the window is greater than 960px I'd like to apply `display: block;` inline style to the class `.main-navigation`. This is what I have so far but I can't get the syntax right.

```
jQuery(window).resize(function($) {
  if ($(window).width() < 960) {
     document.getElementByClass(".main-navigation").style.display = 'block';
  }
 else {}
});
```

Comment: Why not use CSS media queries as they were specifically designed for this purpose?

Comment: I agree with Rory, but if you intend on using js surely you have the sign the wrong way round: `>` = greater than. Also if you are using jQuery, it would be easier to do `$(".main-navigation").css('display', 'block')`

Comment: I'm currently using jQuery to apply the display style, so I was looking for a way to overwrite this in jQuery too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a little off, you've combined native JS with a jQuery selector and the `getElementByClass` function doesn't exist (unless you've created it yourself), try this:

```
$(window).resize(function($) {
    if ($(this).width() > 960) { // note: greater than operator
        $(".main-navigation").css('display', 'block');
    }
}
```

Better yet, you could use a CSS media query for this purpose as its exactly what they were invented for:

```css
@media (min-width: 960px) {
    .main-navigation {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually didn't realise that !important could overwrite an inline applied style. I've just used this instead of the jQuery.

Comment: It can indeed, which is why you should never use it. Use a higher specificity selector if you need to override styles.